# how to make eddittext's value 0 when I leave it blank

Tags: java, android

I am making a Speed Converter app. There's a problem in my if statement. I want my distance/hour/minute/second to be equals to 0 when it is left blank so that it will still compute my formulas. But unfortunately my app keeps crashing when I hit the compute button. Any kind of suggestion or revision will help. Thank you.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    distance = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.distance);
    hour = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hour);
    minute = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.minute);
    second = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.second);

    kph = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.kph);
    kps = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.kps);
    mm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mm);


}

public void computeClick(View view) {
    String d = distance.getText().toString().trim();
    String h = hour.getText().toString().trim();
    String m = minute.getText().toString().trim();
    String s = second.getText().toString().trim();

        Double dis = Double.parseDouble(d);
        Double hr = Double.parseDouble(h);
        Double min = Double.parseDouble(m);
        Double sec = Double.parseDouble(s);

        if (d.equals("")) {
            distance.setText("0");

        }

         if (h.equals("")) {
        hour.setText("0");

        }

         if (m.equals("")) {
        minute.setText("0");

        }

        if (s.equals("")) {
        second.setText("0");

         }

        Double dtok = dis / 1000;
        Double mtoh = min / 60;
        Double stoh = sec / 3600;
        Double htoh = hr / 1;

        Double htos = hr * 3600;
        Double mtos = min * 60;
        Double stos = sec / 1;

        Double htom = hr * 60;
        Double stom = sec / 60;
        Double mtom = min / 1;

        Double totaltimekph = mtoh + stoh + htoh;
        Double totalkph = dtok / totaltimekph;
        kph.setText(Double.toString(totalkph));

        Double totaltimekps = htos + mtos + stos;
        Double totalkps = dtok / totaltimekps;
        kps.setText(Double.toString(totalkps));


        Double totaltimempm = htom + stom + mtom;
        Double totalmpm = dis / totaltimempm;
        mm.setText(Double.toString(totalmpm));

}
```

Comment: Please include the crash logs

Answer (score -1):

You should not call `Double.parseDouble()` if the EditText value is empty. Instead, assign the value as 0 to the variable.

Answer (score -1):

Don't check this way

```
d.equals("")
```

Use this method

```
d.isEmpty()
```

And same for all other EditText variables.